# SUM according to two other fields

Tags: sql, sum, recursive-query

Explanation :
i've a table like this :

| ID | start_pt | end_pt | value | addition | myresult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

It's my first recursive function and I'm trying to increment the value according with tuple n-1 who have start_pt = end_pt but my query returns wrong values (unstead "addition" i get "value"). I'm pretty sure the problems comes from the group by ...with ID.

The fields "addition" is the result i'm trying to get.

Example for id=3, addition  should returns 1 because last tuple is 1 and  start_pt = end_pt.

My query looks like this :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS turbi.flowAdd_v2;
CREATE TABLE turbi.flowAdd_v2 AS
WITH RECURSIVE additionflow (pk,value,id,start_pt,end_pt)
    AS(
        SELECT 
        tu.pk,
        0,
        tu.id,
        tu.start_pt,
        tu.end_pt
        from turbi."input" tu
        LEFT JOIN turbi."input" t2 
        ON tu.start_pt = t2.end_pt
        WHERE t2.end_pt IS NULL
        UNION
        SELECT
        tu.pk,
        tu.value,
        tu.id,
        tu.start_pt,
        tu.end_pt
        FROM additionflow
        JOIN turbi."input" tu
        ON additionflow.end_pt =tu.start_pt
    )
    SELECT SUM(value),id from additionflow GROUP BY value, id;  --i think this is the pb

select * from turbi.flowAdd_v2
```

Comment: Your explanation of what you want to accomplish is not clear.

Comment: You should include the results you actually want for the example data you've provided.

Comment: Sorry it was not clear but the result correspond to the "addition" field

Answer (score 1):

If you are are trying to create the `addition` column, that is just a cumulative sum:

```
select tu.*,
       sum(value) over (order by id) as addition
from turbi."input" tu;
```

Comment: i'have to modify my Where clause but at first sight it seems to work.